# real examples using qunit and jstestrunner?

Tags: javascript, maven, phantomjs, qunit, jstestrunner

I'm trying to set up some javascript unit tests using jstestrunner and qunit, in Maven.  I've worked on many Java unit tests, including setting up the infrastructure, but I'm new at doing this for Javascript.  The setup information on the jstestrunner pages skips critical information.  I would ask about this on a jstestrunner mailing list, but the links for their mailing lists on their codehaus page are inactive, and I can't find a way to contact the dev lead, Christopher Hunt, except perhaps by filing a JIRA, which seems inappropriate.

The usage page talks about setting up phantomjs, but it doesn't say anything about the qunit interface.  I imagine it's probably obvious to people who've used qunit a lot.

I've created the root JUnit test wrapper, but I don't see how to set up the missing link to qunit.

Comment: does this SO question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525311/better-way-to-integrate-maven-qunit-phantomjs?rq=1

Comment: It's more useful background, yes.  It also contributes to my conclusion that Javascript unit testing is still very much in the formative stages.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running some QUnit tests using QUnit, phantomjs, ant and a modified version of [a qunit-runner](https://gist.github.com/gcoop/1588423). The code itself is in a closed-source project, but the gist of it is that I invoke `ant test` on a `build.xml` file with only one target, the `test` target.

The `test` target invokes `phantomjs` with the qunit-runner and some command line arguments. There was some magic involved, such as guessing that the qunit-runner wanted a `package.json` from which it injects the files that is to be tested. The tests themselves get passed using arguments in the ant build file.

I have separate test files for each file that I want tested, and each test file has at least one `module` definition.

The qunit-runner constructs configuration objects for qunit, injects the files to be tested and contains callback hooks for the various stages of the qunit process, which allows me to construct jUnit looking xml to feed into a Jenkins build server page.

I agree with your initial conclusion that the unit-test frameworks of the JavaScript world is still in its infancy. But on the other hand, JavaScript is a very malleable language, and there are few iron-cast conventions to rest a testing framework on. In other languages you also will not get very far without some sort of mocking framework to go with the unit test framework.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a basic setup up and running using QUnit, PhantomJS and js-testrunner.
This link helped some: [jstest-runner-sample-project](https://github.com/ryan-chambers/jstest-runner-sample-project).

For configuration I used:

1. js-testrunner 1.0.2
2. QUnit 1.14.0
3. PhantomJS v1.9.7
4. plexus utils v1.5.7 (required by js-testrunner)
5. jetty v8.1.15 (required by js-testrunner)
6. jackson v1.9.13 (required by jetty)

The test required 4 files:

1. JUnit Java test wrapper - FirstTest.java
2. HTML test wrapper for QUnit - firstTest.html
3. JavaScript file to test - tests.js
4. log4j configuration (standard, basic configuration)

Here are the four files I used for this basic test:

FirstTest.java:

```
package delta;

import org.codehaus.jstestrunner.junit.JSTestSuiteRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JSTestSuiteRunner.class)
@JSTestSuiteRunner.Include(value="firstTest.html")
@JSTestSuiteRunner.ResourceBase({ "src-web/delta", "../lib" })
public class FirstTest {
}
```

firstTest.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/qunit-1.14.0.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/qunit-1.14.0.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="tests.js"></script>
<title>firstTest</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

tests.js:

```
/**
 * Supports firstTest.html
 */
(function() {
  var val;

  module( "First Test", {
    setup: function() {
      val = 1
    }
  });

  test( "hello test", function() {
    ok( val == "1", "Passed!" );
  });
}());
```

I invoked JUnit from within Eclipse, which uses the project root directory therefore requiring the paths to the test files.

After configuring the simple test I can execute them with standard Eclipse Run As->JUnit Test:

[image]